# Can a client connection in CLOSE_WAIT state be terminated from the command line (outside the server)?

Tags: bash, shell, sockets

I've an app running on the port 7496 (server), and there is an unknown process (unknown client) trying to connect to this port and it's not correctly closing the connection, so if I type

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:7496  
COMMAND     PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
JavaAppli 45628 Admin   61u  IPv6 0xb510809c2b4037f3      0t0  TCP *:7496 (LISTEN)
JavaAppli 45628 Admin   62u  IPv6 0xb510809c2b3ffab3      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:7496->127.0.0.1:58507 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

(this show that my server app (45628) but not shows the client PID)

the problem is that this process is blocking me for make new connections with the server: I'm trying to connect another processes to the server but the server is blocking these connections, I'd like close the client (not the server running on the port 7496)

would be possible close this connection? or force close that CLOSE_WAIT connection?, I'm on macOS

thank you so much

Comment: The `CLOSE_WAIT` one *is* already closed from the client's perspective. It's the server's job to close *its* end.

Comment: thanks @CharlesDuffy so I need handle and close this connection from the server?...is it not possible close this through the shell?...

Comment: it *already is* closed, it's just that the server hasn't closed its end of the socket. So this is entirely a fix-a-bug-in-the-server problem.

Comment: Also, the `127.0.0.1` would seem to imply that the "unknown client" is in fact local to the same system - it's not connecting from an external IP address, but from `localhost`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. If one client is blocking others, maybe you need a bigger listen queue? 
   https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen
2. If you need timeouts, maybe use select and/or socket.settimeout() https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout

HTH.

Comment: Note that the OP is using Java, not Python, for their server. The traditional way to write a server in Java involves handing off each inbound connection to a new thread; there are situations where even starting a thread is too slow and you want a pool or other approach, but that's not going to be the case here where the OP has only one client.

Comment: ...before the NIO subsystem's introduction, Java didn't *support* `select()` calls at all. It certainly does today, but regardless, point is that there are enough differences that the OP really needs a Java-specific answer (once they ask a Java-specific question, which they really ought to do in the near future; right now, they're asking how to plaster over their problem from the shell/OS without changing the server process at all).

Comment: Listen-queue has nothing to do with this. It is intended for (the number of) sockets in half-listening state before accept() (where they get their ephemeral portnumber)